# Please provide some feedback for Logo Critique

Tags: logo, critique

This is a logo for a pathology society.

Parameters are: Symmetry. Science Colors, Blues & Greens. Connected circles representing diversity, connection, synergy.

I have an entire brief and hundreds of versions if needed.

[image: ASIP logo]

Comment: Have you checked this at a reduced size? I suspect that line of blue type will become unreadable at smaller sizes.

Comment: Something is wrong with the images; choosing e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j8bls.png or clicking through to the full-size image gets me black on black.

Comment: @tripleee that's because it's a transparent PNG, nothing necessarily wrong with the image

Comment: I think you need to focus your question a bit more, it's too broad to give critique on all aspects. You can also ask for feedback on the Looking Glass chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass

Comment: sorry, I am new to this forum. it said I didn't have enough tokens to join

Comment: You can earn reputation points by submitting edit suggestions. Some people never learn to spell properly so there's a never-ending supply of new posts with "alot", "definately" etc in them. (Take care to fix all errors you can find in those posts, not just the lowest-hanging fruit, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The tracking is very uneven; the space between the A and the rest of SIP is visually much larger than between the other letters in the display text.

Similarly, the circles are aligned visually with the upper edge of the A, but floating freely above the loop in the P. Choose one principle or the other (probably shrink from the right so as to align with the visual slope of the P).

The semicircles are not round; the squashed form seems to violate several of your principles.

The blue semicircles are similar enough that the difference in color seems like maybe a mistake. Having noticed that, I guess the grays have the same issue, though it's less noticeable (but in some sense more disturbing once you notice).

Comment: thank you. I will try to incorporate these. the difference in color is intentional to represent diversity.

Comment: I do not see a space to upload another image in comments? Where should I do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can edit your question, upload a second image, capture the URL, and cancel the edit; the image will still remain behind the URL.

Answer (score 0):

- Everything is a bit too close together. Needs better spacing overall.
- Jumping from blue to black to gray to blue again seems confusing. Maybe do the half-Audi part in blue, then everything else in black.
- Thicker font weight for the tagline under ASIP.
- Taglines are usually black or dark grey and for a reason.
- Font selection kind of sterile. Is that Myriad?

Comment: 1. ok 2. a gradiation? 3. okay 4. yes, the choice of the EO. Any typographical suggestions that I can incorporate?